# Chrome autofill alternative possibilities

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, plugins, auto-form-fill

It happens again again and again, chrome doesn't auto fill some information from saved autofill form.
There is many reasons it happens and most of them is the HTML/JavaScript on the sites.
It is why I have tried to find some solution for Chrome which **independent** of some form/auto detection/payment detection/password/what ever possible detection is.
Is there any possibility to have autofill function based on first letters typing independent of which form I fill out? Like in smartphones.

I expect this behavior for all forms in all websites:

| I type | I get suggestion before hit enter |
| --- | --- |
| su | superuser |
| sup | superuser |
| st | stackoverflow |
| stack | stackoverflow |
| chr | chrome |